# entity vs. dapper datetime check not worker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dapper

I have entity and also use dapper, I have 1 form with 2 date fields... named **before** and **after** so users can search in between those dates. The one from entity works perfectly but the one from dapper does not work for some reason what could possibly be wrong 
here is the entity one

```
var article = (from x in db.Articles
                           where  x.created >= before && x.created <= after
                           select x);
```

and here is the one from dapper

```
var article = sqlConnection.Query<Article>("Select * from articles where created>=@befor AND created<=@afte ", new { befor = before, afte = after});
```

and yes I have all the connections for Dapper working as it does go to the database but for some reason its not picking records between those 2 dates..any suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dapper is *just* a wrapper around raw TSQL (with a slight caveat around `in`, where dapper adds some magic to make varadic "in" queries simpler). So; if it works in TSQL it *should* work fine in dapper, ***as long as*** your inputs make sense. For example, I am ***assuming*** that `before` and `after` in this example are typed as non-nullable `DateTime`, i.e.

```
DateTime before = ..., after = ...;
var article = sqlConnection.Query<Article>(
    "Select * from articles where created>=@befor AND created<=@afte ",
    new { befor = before, afte = after});
```

as a side note, it would perhaps be more *obvious* to just use:

```
DateTime before = ..., after = ...;
var article = sqlConnection.Query<Article>(
    "Select * from articles where created>=@before AND created<=@after",
    new { before, after });
```

but fundamentally, as long as those parameters have non-`null` values that are `DateTime`s, it should work fine.

Comment: @user1591668 can you clarify what the issue *was*, for the benefit of later readers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here could be that the `before` and `after` values are send as `string` and the current locale may be causing the date to be interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: they both have the **DateTime? before** **DateTime? after** but i guess somehow dapper is getting it confused.

Comment: @user1591668 define "confused"? also: what are their **values** - is either of those `null`? because a `>=` / `<=` against `null` will always produce zero results.

Comment: I was saying that maybe dapper is treating it as a string but both of those fields are not null as my action is **public ActionResult search(DateTime? before,DateTime? after)** so after i click submit on the form i see the values up top; although I am using the jquery datepicker which has the dates in the form of thur, june 6,2013 .

Comment: @user1591668 no, dapper doesn't change the type of parameters; if `before`/`after` are `DateTime`/`DateTime?`, then they will **go to ADO.NET** as `DateTime`.